# Storing derived variables in react state doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to write a component that's basically a transferlist, but for the sake of this problem I simplified it a lot.

See below example: the react-admin component gets 2 inputs: a sub-list of selected items `record[source]` (`source` points to a property on the `record` object, this is `react-admin` specific), and a list with all possible items `allItems`.
I want the component to display 2 lists: the list of selected items, and a list of NOT selected items. The list of selected items is given, and I calculate the list of NOT selected items by simply filtering the list containing all items and removing the selected ones.

However for some reason (definitely related to my limited javascript/react experience), I can't get this to work.

What I'm seeing in the below code is that the `left` variable is working just fine, and displaying the selected items. However the `right` variable always seems to be empty, event though I check that the `unselected` variable contains the wanted list when doing the `useState(unselected)` call.

Note: the items are just strings, and I can see that the variable `unselected` contains the items I want just fine. So the problem is related to using state, not calculating the unselected list.

I'm pretty sure I'm just bumping into the limits of my React / Redux state knowledge here, but I'm not sure why this is happening and how to fix it. Any input very welcome!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const TransferList = ({record, source, allItems}) => {

  var unselected = allItems.filter(name => !(record[source].includes(name)));
  const [left, setLeft] = useState(record[source]);
  const [right, setRight] = useState(unselected);

  return (
    <div>
      Selected:
      <ul>
        { left.map(s => <li>{s}</li>) }
      </ul>
      Unselected:
      <ul>
        { right.map(s => <li>{s}</li>) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just get somehow your allItems is updated then your should useEffect to track the update from the allItems:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const unselected = allItems.filter(name => !(record[source].includes(name)));
  setRight(unselected)
},[allItems])
```

Please check if it work

Comment: Yes that works :D !

I knew it would be something with `useEffect`, I just didn't know how...

The `allItems` variable is loaded dynamically in the parent element.

So I guess what happens here is when the component is initialised, it just copies in the current value of `allItems` and that's never updated?
And by using `useEffect()` it creates a hook that is called whenever the `allItems` variable is changes in the parent and allows you to update the derived variable?

Comment: Yes cause it doesn't work like class component which you can use the componentDidUpdate to rerender your component. Here you useState and when your initial value inside changed it won't rerender the component. Then I use additional useEffect to handle the case that allItems changed. And after it changed we call setRight that time component will rerender.